# The river shore problem

Tags: geometry

I have a one strange question. Hope that it'll be fine here.
Imagine we have a moving point in an infinite length and 2 meters width corridor. This point needs to get to one of the borders of a corridor and reach it. 
At the first moment of time, our dot is located somwhere in that corridor, it's **not stated, where exactly**. The question - Is there a path which certainly leads to the wall, for which the maximum distance between the first location of a point and the border will be not more than

a)$483$ sm

b)$462$ sm

c)$458$ sm

By the way, we consider our corridor is a one dark place, so our point **can not see** where to go.

I came up with an idea that our point's trajectory will be circular. That's guaranteed that a point will reach the border no matter where it starts. But I can't figure out how to use this restrictions to solve the problem. Help me please.

---

Of cource the question is not just to tell whether there is such path, but also try to figure out a trajectory equation.

Sorry for tags, don't know what to put here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solved by Ani Adhikari and Jim Pitman, The shortest planar arc of width 1, American Mathematical Monthly 96 (1989) 309-327. If you can't access that paper, another proof of the Adhikari-Pitman result is given [here](http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~tmchan/river.pdf).

Comment: Well, the width is 1, hope I can work out the solution based on this document for 2 m. width.